# How to test Cordova/ionic app on iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building an app which now runs fine in the iOS emulator, so I now want to test the app on an iOS device. I registered with the Apple Developer Program and ran `ionic run ios`, which ended with the following message:

> Code Sign error: No provisioning profiles found: No non–expired provisioning profiles were found.
>   CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.2'

So I opened XCode and went to `Preferences > Accounts` and added my Apple ID. I then clicked `View Details...` and then the refresh icon so it fetched two Signing Identities. The box below which should display the Provisioning Profiles is empty though:

[image]

I then read [this article on the Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html) which explains that I need to:

1. Set a bundle ID
2. Assign my app to a team
3. Create the Team Provisioning Profile

The bundle ID should supposedly be set in XCode. Because I am under the assumption that the bundle ID is set in my ionic `config.xml` file I'm unsure of how to proceed though.

Does anybody know how I can (preferably very easily) test my app on iOS devices? All tips are welcome!

Comment: you can check bundleId on Xcode by clicking on project title. It is needed only if you want to export your app for beta testing or app store. To run on device you just need to set your provisioning profiles properly.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to create a new project into Xcode, as soon it is created is showing the General tab, under Identity is showing a message saying that can not find the proper certified, something like that, and there is a button "Fix..."
just click it, the passport is requested and you are done.
I just try again and works. Xcode fixed my provisioning profiles sync for me.

Comment: open your ionic .xcodeproj file in Xcode. Click on the project on the left side panel. You should see the "Fix..." button.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955680/418974

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- Select Preferences from Xcode
- Go to accounts and select agent name
- Select view details to check status of your profiles
- Select any profile and click refresh on corner below to update profiles.
  This should update your profile with expiration dates
  [image]

Comment: I tried this, but I still don't get any provisioning profiles. Any other idea? Do I need to register something else somewhere first, or what am I missing?

Comment: can you try to profile using plus symbol.In your screenshot shows no provisioning profile in below section

Comment: I tried clicking `+ > iOS Development` and `+ > iOS Distribution`, but no unfortunately still changes. Any more ideas?

Comment: From targets select your product name then select general where you can set team under identity option.Also goto build settings and go to code signing option set debug and release options with iOS developer.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `project General` and downgrade to `8.1`.

[image]